# Как в js сделать ссылку верхнего блока не кликабельной при fixed со скроллингом?

Tags: javascript, css

У меня есть рабочий джаваскрипт, реализующий наезд на верхний блок. Он с fixed. При скроллинге контента, блок плавно исчезает. Однако, в блоке есть ссылки, которые остаются кликабельными. В результате, случайный клик по исчезновшему блоку, приводит к переходам по его ссылкам. Возможно ли сделать их не кликабельными в начале процесса скроллинга?

**Скрипт:**

```
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  Array.from(elements).forEach(function(element) {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
      var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      var opacity = 1 - (scrollTop / element.offsetHeight);
      opacity = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, opacity));
      element.style.opacity = opacity.toString();
      if (scrollTop >= scrollThreshold) {
        element.style.opacity = '0';
      }
    });
  });
}
setOpacityOnScroll('aetitisy-site-header', 200);
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Выбирай:

1. ```
   visibility: hidden
   ```
2. ```
   pointer-events: none
   ```
3. ```
   display: none
   ```
4. ```
   opacity: 0
   ```

Но учитывая что 4й пункт в коде уже есть, ты делаешь не то, что пишешь, поэтому тебе поможет только второй пункт, но пользователи тебя проклянут за нерабочие полувидимые ссылки.

---

> Получается, реализовать отключение ссылок при старте скроллинга — невозможно?

Ну я ж сказал - второй пункт списка:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
  element.style.opacity = Math.max(0, 1 - scrollTop / element.offsetHeight)
  element.style.pointerEvents = scrollTop < 3 ? 'all' : 'none'
})
```

Comment: Выбор без выбора? Я потому и сослался на скрипт, чтобы понять — реально ли сделать нужное мне в нём. Насколько понимаю, в CSS это не получится.

Comment: @milcheloveck, ну так в нём это уже сделано в строке `element.style.opacity = '0';`. Раз тебя это не устраивает, значит ты хочешь частично прозрачную ссылку сделать некликабельной (хотя и не написал об этом в вопросе). Кстати, в коде полно лишнего.

Comment: Допустим. Получается, реализовать отключение ссылок при старте скроллинга — невозможно? Мне трудно с этим согласиться. Может быть есть решение? В CSS это всё равно не получится.

Comment: @milcheloveck, может всё-таки прочитаешь ответ? Там же русским языком написано, как сделать.

Comment: Вариант 1. Скрыть ссылки путями указанными в ответе сверху. Вариант 2. Через `javascript` у ссылок данные из атрибута `href` заменить например на `javascript:0` предварительно запомнив их в атрибут `data-href`. В момент когда работу нужно будет восстановить - поменять данные местами. Вариант 3. Через тот же `javascript` заменить `<a href ...>` и `</a>` у нужных ссылок на какой-нибудь `span` (со своим стилем), когда нужно - все вернуть. Вариант 4... Вариант 5.. Вариант N - включайте фантазию. Я использую - Вариант 2, если ссылки нельзя по каким-то причинам скрывать.

Comment: Феоктист, логика отключения ссылок понятна:
```$(document).ready(function(){$('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('You just tried to open a link. And jQuery prevented it.');
    });
});```
Однако здесь не хватает того самого триггера, который отключит ссылки при старте скроллинга. 
Буду признателен за полный код: в CSS мне всё понятно, но JS — туман. Спасибо.

Comment: @ФеоктистПупырышкин, если хотел написать ответ, то и пиши в ответ. К моему ответу твой комментарий не имеет никакого отношения. Впрочем, в качестве ответа он тоже сильно так себе.

Comment: @milcheloveck, нет, не понятна. Я же тебе русским языком написал, как сделать. Второй пункт!

Comment: @Qwertiy вежливость не Ваш конек...

Comment: @milcheloveck у вас же есть `if (scrollTop >= scrollThreshold) { ... }` где Вы скрываете блок, добавьте туда кусок кода который переберет все ссылки в блоке, возьмёт у них значение атрибута `href`, добавит их в атрибут `data-href`, а значение `href` поменяет например на `javascript:void();`.

Comment: @ФеоктистПупырышкин, вот уж в том месте ему совершенно нечего делать.

Comment: @milcheloveck, дополнил ответ.